# Google Analytics API get Profile ID instead or with Domains

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This is how I print Domains from any Google Analytics account.  How do I print Profile IDs instead (or with the Domains)?

```
global $_params, $output_title, $output_body;
$output_title = 'Adwords';
$output_nav = '<li><a href="'.$scriptUri.'?logout">Logout</a></li>'."\n";
$output_body = '<h1>Google Adwords Access demo</h1>
                <p>The following domains are in your Google Adwords account</p><ul>';
$props = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("~all");
foreach($props['items'] as $item) {
    $output_body .= sprintf('<li>%1$s</li>', $item['name']);
}
$output_body .= '</ul>';
```

This line is the function that gets the Domains:

```
$props = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("~all");
```

I need something to get Profile IDs for multiple Domains now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This example below should help you print all the profile ids for a particular account XXXX and property UA-XXXX-Y.

```
 /**
 * This example requests a list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
 */
$profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles('XXXX', 'UA-XXXX-Y');

foreach ($profiles->getItems() as $profile) {
    print("view (profile) id: $profile->getId()");
}
```

You can checkout the API [documentation for view (profiles)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list) for more detailed examples.

You may also find it useful to use the [account summaries api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list). It provides an easy way to iterate through all levels of the Google Analytics Accounts -> Properties -> view (profiles)

```
$accounts = $analytics->management_accountSummaries
      ->listManagementAccountSummaries();

foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $account) {
  $html = <<<HTML
<pre>
Account id   = {$account->getId()}
Account kind = {$account->getKind()}
Account name = {$account->getName()}
HTML;

  // Iterate through each Property.
  foreach ($account->getWebProperties() as $property) {
  $html .= <<<HTML
Property id          = {$property->getId()}
Property kind        = {$property->getKind()}
Property name        = {$property->getName()}
Internal property id = {$property->getInternalWebPropertyId()}
Property level       = {$property->getLevel()}
Property URL         = {$property->getWebsiteUrl()}
HTML;

    // Iterate through each view (profile).
    foreach ($property->getProfiles() as $profile) {
      $html .= <<<HTML
Profile id   = {$profile->getId()}
Profile kind = {$profile->getKind()}
Profile name = {$profile->getName()}
Profile type = {$profile->getType()}
HTML;
    }
  }
  $html .= '</pre>';
  print $html;
}
```